# Box shadow is covering a small portion of the DIV

Tags: css

I have the following Box Shadow css style. Unfortunately it is covering a very small portion on the top of the mainContent DIV. The rest of the DIV length is without any shadow. What am I doing wrong?

```
.mainContent {width: 85%; margin: auto; max-width:1400px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 26px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 9px 26px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         0px 9px 26px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);}
```

Comment: You must be using `overflow: hidden;` for the wrapper element

Comment: .mainContent is the main wrapper of the page content...

Comment: Does it have `overflow: hidden`? if yes than remove

Comment: on the contrary I added overflow: hidden to the .mainContent and it worked.

Comment: So it may be the float issue, not sure but anyways it worked for you so great...

Answer (score 0):

You should set the height property to auto.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RWsE6/1/)

```
.mainContent {width: 85%; margin: auto; max-width:1400px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 26px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 9px 26px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         0px 9px 26px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
height:auto

}

   <div class='mainContent'>
        <div style='height:50px; width:50px; border:1px solid'></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Well the DIV height depends on its content so I can't give it a fixed height. The percentage doesn't work.

Comment: @Gloria, then you should set it to auto or inherit (updated answer).